# Insertion sorting algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am creating an insertion algorithm for sorting in C++. Here it is:

```
void mySort2(int a[], const int num_elements)
{
    int x[num_elements];
    bool inserted(false);

    x[0] = a[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        inserted = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] < x[j])
            {
                inserted = true;
                memmove(x + j + 1, x+j, (num_elements - j - 1)*sizeof(int*));
            x[j]=a[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!inserted)
        {
            x[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    print(x, num_elements);
}
```

When tested with the data set:

```
int num_elements(7);
int a[] = {2, 1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6};
```

The code works as expected, printing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
However, when I make the input any bigger than 7, the program has a Segmentation Error and dumps the core. I have tried data sets smaller than 7 elements and it again works as expected.

Do I need to be using dynamically allocated memory, or is there and error in my algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: Run it in your debugger to find the line which causes the seg fault. Use vectors which will be bounds checked in good debug compilers.

Comment: If you are using C++ you should not be using a non standard VLA `int x[num_elements];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(int*)` may not equal `sizeof(int)`. Whether it does or not, you meant to write `sizeof(int)`. You may be moving too much data and stomping over some random memory.

Oh and just for fun here's a suboptimal (but so little code!) insertion sort:

```
for(auto i = first; i != last; ++i)
    std::rotate(std::upper_bound(first, i, *i), i, std::next(i));
```

Comment: depends on what cpu architecture he has

Comment: Are you sure, that's the problem? In many compilers on 32-bit architectures `sizeof(int)` will be equal to `sizeof(pointer_type)`.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that's the problem, it's definitely a mistake though.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek What about architectures in which it isn't? A bug is a bug, even if it's currently sleeping.